# Toggle Content via Menu (Pure HTML and CSS)

Tags: html, css, modal-dialog

Say I have three div's which contain unique content;

- div1 = Is a Photoshop guide
- div2 = Contains a gallery of images
- div3 = Lists personal contact details

When my page loads they all need to be hidden;

- div1 = hidden
- div2 = hidden
- div3 = hidden

They are also laid ontop of one another (occupy the same space having the same width, but varying heights).

There's a horizontal menu above these divs that trigger their visbilities;

| View 1 | View 2 | View 3 |

If a user clicks 'View 1', div1 becomes visible;

- div1 = visible
- div2 = hidden
- div3 = hidden

If a user clicks 'View 2', only div2 is visible;

- div1 = hidden
- div2 = visible
- div3 = hidden

And the same for clicking 'View 3';

- div1 = hidden
- div2 = hidden
- div3 = visible

My current solution is available via JSFiddle here;

http://jsfiddle.net/t6cU4/

only using check-boxes and opacity settings with `<div>`, `<label>` and `<input>`

How do I go about this using only HTML and CSS (no scripts) in the smallest way possible?

- What I'm trying to achieve is a singular page design, where no external pages are used
- A background (or active) style would also be of use for the menu items (so the user knows which div they are viewing)
- The problem with the current solution is that the labels and have no selection effect and the divs do not overlap (they appear below each other like a list inside of overlapping). The logo also disappears along with item 3 when clicking a label

Comment: Use radio buttons, labels, and the CSS :checked selector. http://alistapart.com/article/radio-controlled-web-design

Answer (score 2):

The trick is add a `<label>` tag after a `<input type="checkbox">` and in CSS, add the selector `:checked` for the input, like a trigger.

**HTML**

```
<input class="trigger" id="1" type="checkbox">
<label for="1">Click me</label>
<div>Surprise!</div>

<br><br>

<input class="trigger" id="2" type="checkbox">
<label for="2">Click me too</label>
<div>Surprise again!</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.trigger + label + div /*This selects the div that is placed after a label that's after a element with 'trigger' class*/
{
    display:none; /*hiding the element*/
}

.trigger /*This selects a element with class 'trigger'*/
{
    display:none; /*hiding the element*/
}

.trigger:checked + label + div /*This selects the div that is placed after a label that's after a CHECKED input with class 'trigger'*/
{
    display:block; /*showing the element*/
}
```

**### [See Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HN9am/)**

Or

**#### [See Fiddle With Explanations](http://jsfiddle.net/HN9am/2/)**

### 07.30.2014 - UPDATE:

You said you want the divs appearing without any menu deformations, right? Try to put all `<div>`'s in the bottom and put every corresponding `<input>` before that. The labels stay on top.

Just like that:

```
<label for="1">Click me</label>

<label for="2">Click me too</label>

<br/><br/>

<input class="trigger" id="1" type="checkbox"/>
<div class="cont"><strong>1st Title</strong><br/>And 1st content.</div>

<input class="trigger" id="2" type="checkbox"/>
<div class="cont"><strong>2nd Title</strong><br/>And 2nd content.</div>
```

and in CSS:

```
.trigger:checked + div {
    display:block;
}
```

#### -> See new Fiddle <-

***(Sorry if my english is bad)***

Comment: Your English is great! ^_^ Yeah, I am using this particular technique as well (viewable at  http://alejchotest.weebly.com/). The only problem is making those labels appear horizontally, with the div's (the corresponding content) appearing below the menu items (the entire navigation bar). The content appears within the menu deforming it

Comment: @AlfredJohnCacho Sorry for take too long to answer you. I'm so sorry, now I think I get it. I did a modification into my JSFiddle and I think it's working the way you was wanting, [see HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/HN9am/4/). Oh, and thanks for saying my english is great! =D. **NOTE:** this is my 2nd comment, I deleted the 1st because I have understood wrong.

Comment: WOW THANKS!!! This is almost what I need!!!! Great work!!! Is there a way to fix the divs appearing above/below each other however (or only have one or none appear at any one time)?

Comment: I have updated the question, I solved the transition effects, the only problem now is overlapping and visibility toggles

Comment: @AlfredJohnCacho Hey, you can modify the `<input type='checkbox'>` to `<input type='radio'>`, I think it'll be solved. Sorry for take too long to answer... again.

Comment: @AlfredJohnCacho Oh, and if I helped you, **please** don't forget to **accept** my answer, so the others can use it.

Answer (score 0):

Try different CSS menus. You can grab a lot from google.
Here are some samples collected from web:

```
http://www.smashingapps.com/2013/02/18/48-free-dropdown-menu-in-html5-and-css3.html

http://css3menu.com/enterprise-green.html
```

Comment: Great samples, although I'm not talking about a dropdown menu, it's large content appearing after clicking a menu item

Comment: @AlfredJohnCacho You may try javascript or jquery to achieve this. using jquery, this is pretty simple to achieve bit using CSS only, you can have hover effects but not sure if you can achieve on click events as you are looking for.